# Format HTML string with C#

Tags: c#, html, formatting, string-formatting

I'm searching for analog of Beautify Code function of http://prettydiff.com/ on C#. 
For example I have this string:

```
<div><div><input type="radio" value="radio" id="radio_0">Radio</div><div><input type="radio" value="radio" id="radio_1">Radio</div><div><input type="radio" value="radio" id="radio_2">Radio</div><div><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" value="checkbox" id="checkbox_3">Checkbox</div><div><p id="text_4">HELLO</p></div><div><p id="text_5">HELLO</p></div></div>
```

And then I want to get something like this:

```
<div>
     <div><input id="radio_0" type="radio" value="radio">Radio</div>
     <div><input id="radio_1" type="radio" value="radio">Radio</div>
     <div><input id="radio_2" type="radio" value="radio">Radio</div>
     <div><input id="checkbox_3" name="checkbox" type="checkbox" value="checkbox">Checkbox</div>
     <div><p id="text_4">HELLO</p></div>
     <div><p id="text_5">HELLO</p></div>
```

If you know tools that can help me or have any ideas, please write them :) Ty.

Answer (score 1):

Try any of the HTML-to-XHTML parsers, i.e. [HtmlAgilityPack](https://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/), [SgmlReader](https://github.com/MindTouch/SGMLReader), etc.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Visual Studio you can press <kbd>Ctrl + K</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl + D</kbd>.

You can also find it in the menu under Edit > Advanced > Format Document.

**EDIT**

I just noticed that the menu in VS 2010, VS 2008, and VS 2005 the option is <kbd>Ctrl + E</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl + D</kbd>.  I can use <kbd>Ctrl + K</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl + D</kbd> in the older versions, but I cannot use <kbd>Ctrl + E</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl + D</kbd> in VS 2013.

I do not have VS 2012 on this machine so I cannot confirm at this time if <kbd>Ctrl + E</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl + D</kbd> works, but I have always used <kbd>Ctrl + K</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl + D</kbd> in the past.

[Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/5zwses53%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is additional information on how to customize the buttons if you do not like the defaults.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution is resharper.

I am using it and i customized it for myself aswell.